# What's the best option? Characters in the comic series, Characters of the comic series, or character from the comic series? Read more and answer me:

Tags: prepositions

I'm Brazilian and the author of the comic series *Albert & Einstein e Sua Turma* and *Nina e Zoca* (in English, *Albert & Einstein and Their Gang* and *Nina and Zoca*).

In Portuguese, I use in my YouTube description videos:

> personagens das séries de histórias em quadrinhos (no Brasil) ou
> bandas desenhadas (em Portugal e em Angola) *Albert & Einstein e Sua
> Turma* e *Nina e Zoca*.

And, in Spanish, I use:

> personajes de las
> series de historietas *Albert & Einstein y su pandilla* y *Nina y
> Zoca*.

But, in English, I don't know at the moment if is the best option is:

> characters in the comic series *Albert & Einstein and Their Gang* and
> *Nina and Zoca*

> characters of the comic series *Albert & Einstein and Their Gang* and
> *Nina and Zoca*

or:

> characters from the comic series *Albert & Einstein and Their Gang*
> and *Nina and Zoca*

According Google search, all the three options are good and right. Also have the option

> *Albert & Einstein and Their Gang* and *Nina and Zoca* comic series characters

but I prefer start with characters, put in the middle the comic series, and conclude with the series names (I think that becomes much more strong, harmonic, and expressive after all.

Comment: Your issue is quite complicated. Do you realize that you need an English editor (revisor) ? In any case, personally, I would use: animated series, or comic book series, not comic series, as that can mean **funny** series (uma série engraçada).  It would depend on what you are actually saying in your context. "from" and "in" are used to express different things, unlike Portuguese which only uses "de". And I would forget "of" in most cases. (Sou tradutora e intérprete). So, what do you want to say exactly?

Comment: Your three options seem fairly similar to me and better than your fourth one. I agree with @Lambie that avoiding comic series would be good. The phrase _graphic novel_ seem to be current these days at least in the UK but that refers to a single book of course.

Comment: All three options mean different things, and your purpose naturally leads to one over the other. What is your goal here?

Comment: You have not dealt with the issue in English of "comic series". If it is like a movie, we say "animated series". bandas desenhadas are comic strips or comic books in English.

Comment: @Sávio Por favor, você poderia nós responder?

Comment: It depends on context (afraid I don't know Portuguese). If you're talking about the characters as they feature in the series, then "in" works although other prepositions could be OK; if the characters are taken out from the series to be considered separately or to appear in other works then "from" might be better. "Rachel, Phoebe, and Monica are characters in Friends"; "James Bond is a character from Ian Fleming's novels who has appeared in many motion pictures".

Answer (score 0):

The first three work. The last is clumsy.

I much prefer "the characters in ...". The phrase "the characters from ..." suggests that you are about to discuss those characters in some context other than the place they live.

"The characters of ..." sounds awkward to me.

And, as in the comments, "comic series" isn't quite right.

Answer (score 0):

I would say "in," but an opinion isn't worth much without hard data, so I did an a Google [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=characters%20in%20the%20book%2Ccharacters%20from%20the%20book%2Ccharacters%20of%20the%20book%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccharacters%20in%20the%20book%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccharacters%20from%20the%20book%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccharacters%20of%20the%20book%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ccharacters%20in%20the%20book%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccharacters%20from%20the%20book%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccharacters%20of%20the%20book%3B%2Cc0) of the three, replacing "comic series" with "book" in order to generate a larger data sample. Google Ngram concurs, clearly indicating that "in" is far and away the most common preposition to use with "in" being used 7 times more often than "of," which is used three times more often than "from." While I believe the difference between "of" and "from" could merit a deeper dive into the data as there may be contextual differences involving the usage of "of" skewing the results, what matters here is how "in" so predominates as the prepoosition of choice that it is well beyond any statistical margin of error skewing the results.

[image]

Comment: Only context will tell here. I fail to see how ngram helps anything here....especially since de in Spanish and Portuguese translate to of or from or the null set.

Comment: @Lambie - Yes, only context will tell here. My including a link to the Ngram findings' myriad contextual examples is to show such context, they being far too numerous to include in the answer itself. As for Portuguese and Spanish, having served a two-year mission in Portugal and getting my master's from Zaragoza in Spain, I'm fluent in both and aware of what "de" means in each and how its translation into English isn't always as straightforward as just replacing it with "of" or "from." Both sometimes use "de" in places where English uses other prepositions, like "in"— and "out," too, actually.

Comment: Benjamin, look, My point is still that ngrams is simply not relevant here. As for the language-related degrees, I don't feel the need to put them all up here but believe me, having gone through the Sorbonne's ESIT says it all....Also, I am an interpreter (Spanish, Portuguese, French <>English).

Comment: Really? So am I. That's what I do for the US gov't— well, not French, oh là là! What a coincidence, though. I just so rarely run into anyone who's a Portuguese-Spanish-English polyglot and professional interpreter-translator, so it's a pleasure to meet you, @Lambie. Obviously, you've French, too, which I just muddle in but embarrassingly should know better since my ex of two years was French-speaking Swiss. She'd moved to the States to learn English, though, so we spoke English and I never got a leg up on French. Anyway, this is me shaking your hand  and agreeing to disagree on the Ngrams.

Answer (score 0):

**de** in Portuguese can be **from or of** in English.

- Characters **in** the series **of** comic-strip drawings *Albert & Einstein and Their Gang and Nina* and Zoca are very funny.
- Characters **from the** series of comic-strip drawings *Albert & Einstein and Their Gang and Nina and Zoca* came to life when a major Hollywood studio decided to make a feature-length film using them.

Now, **bandas desenhadas** are comics or comic books or drawings for comics.

comic series is not a standard English term here.

The standard terms are:
comics
comic strips
comic-strip drawings

Judging by what one can see on YouTube, these are drawings on paper of these characters and there are a series of these drawings.

- **series of comics** doesn't work as the drawings on a single sheets of paper
- **series of comic strips** doesn't work either as I didn't see any comic strips.
- A series of comic-strip drawings seems to be what they are.